# Get property named post in restangular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, post, restangular

I'm getting a list of 'postrows' with the following code

```
$scope.postrows = {};
Restangular.all('/postrows').getList().then(function(data){
  $scope.postrows = data;
});
```

The JSON which is returned looks like

```
{
  id: 1,
  post: {
    id: 1,
    postcategory: 1,
    account: "0005",
    description: "Grond",
    sequence_number: 1
  },
  amount: 2343.56,
},
```

But when I loop trough the list of items:

```
angular.forEach($scope.postrows, function(postrow) {
  console.log(postrow);
  console.log(postrow.post);
}
```

And want to retrieve for example `postrow.post` I receive the `post` function from restangular. How can I get the `post` object like it is in the json file.

I'm not allowed to change the name `post` to something else.

Comment: Where is your code that you use to loop through this?

Comment: Just edited the question.

Comment: What does `postrow` look like when you log it? does it contain the `post` attribute as you expect it? What are the results of `console.log(postrow)`

Comment: It is already a function when logging. Also when i log $scope.postrows the `post` is already a function instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Restangular actually overrides your post object with Restangular object.

For that, just change all your post methods to another name like the following:

```
Restangular.setRestangularFields({
  post: "$post"
});
```

From now on, post object won't be overriden and you can do `Restangular.all('places').$post(newObject)` to create a new one!